# SaveToFile and then open it formating text weird

Tags: database, file, delphi, delphi-7

Okay so I am writing a program that imports a database to an text file Via (SaveToFile command) .But when I open the file normally it gives me.

```
 TG!     ¶’ò?²Ï# ª _þX        g Ò­cöëÏ°ã ª ?               Á<Ž¶ëmÐö ª _þX               
                         |  ¾"µÈó\Î­å ª Dw=     ÿÿ†    ÿÿ"        I        Á<Ž¶ëmÐö ª _þX                          2          .      " C l i e n t s "  C l i e n t s      + ð   I D    I D     
   ÿ   Z   ÿÿÿÿC ð   S u r e n a m e    S u r e n a m e ‚    ÿ   ÿ   j     ÿÿC ð   P a s s w o r d    P a s s w o r d     
   ÿ   z     ÿÿ3 ð   N a m e    N a m e ‚    ÿ   ÿ   j     ÿÿK ð  
 M o n e y   P a i d   
 M o n e y   P a i d        ÿ   z     ÿÿK ð  
 M o n e y   O w e d   
 M o n e y   O w e d        ÿ   z     ÿÿ[ ð   O n c e O f f   C l i e n t    O n c e O f f   C l i e n t     ÿ   ÿ   Z     ÿÿC ð   P h o n e   I D    P h o n e   I D     
   ÿ   z     ÿÿÿ   a w e    a w e                   Ó–I
```

Here is my code:

```
procedure TfrmRawDATA.btnStoreFeedClick(Sender: TObject);
  var
      StoreFeed : string;
      StoreFeedFile: TextFile;
      data     : string;
begin

begin
  if (FileExists('C:\Users\ASROCK\Desktop\IT-PAT 2014\PAT Fase 3\StoreFeedFile.txt')) then
  begin
    DeleteFile('C:\Users\ASROCK\Desktop\IT-PAT 2014\PAT Fase 3\StoreFeedFile.txt');
    ShowMessage('Save file deleted!');
  end
  else
  AssignFile(StoreFeedFile,'Test.txt');
  FileSetAttr('C:\Users\ASROCK\Desktop\IT-PAT 2014\PAT Fase 3\StoreFeedFile.txt', faReadOnly);

  dmMJCPlus.tblClients.SaveToFile('C:\Users\ASROCK\Desktop\IT-PAT 2014\PAT Fase 3\StoreFeedFile.txt');
end;
end;
```

I just wanna know how to set like the file type or something so it doesn't give me that text.

Comment: If tblClients is a TClientDataSet, the default format is dfBinary. Other options include XML and UT8-based XML.

Comment: okay so how to I change it from dfbinary to something I can read?

Comment: ..tblClients.SaveToFile('...', dfXML);

Comment: Try this sample [TCustomClientDataSet.SaveToFile](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/DBClient_TCustomClientDataSet_SaveToFile.html) Method

Comment: Gives me undeclared identifier:'dfXML'

Comment: TCustomClientDataSet.SaveToFile still gives same error? dmMJCPlus.tblClients.SaveToFile('C:\Users\ASROCK\Desktop\IT-PAT 2014\PAT Fase 3\StoreFeedFile.txt '+ 'StoreFeedFile.XML', dfXML);

Comment: I do not understand that one sorry can you please elaborate.

Comment: Do you really have a ClientDataSet or an ADOTable, query ..?

Comment: ADOTable I have never used  ClientDataSet.

Comment: @user - That comment is missing a comma so that I don't understand what you have. Anyway, if it's ADO then you use 'pfXML'.

Comment: Now it gives me Gives me undeclared identifier:'pfXML'

Comment: @user - Include 'adodb' or 'dbclient' in your uses clause, as appropriate.

Comment: AWESOME Thanks for the help you're awesome, thanks for not giving up.

Comment: How do I mark it as done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default saving format for ADO table/query and ClientDataSet is binary. You have the option of using XML though. You need to specify it in the call to `SaveToFile`:

```
ClientDataSet.SaveToFile('...', dfXML);
```

or

```
ADOTable.SaveToFile('...', pfXML);
```

Having a file extension of '.xml' should achieve the same, looking at the source, though it would seem it didn't turn out to be the case for you (as you seem to have tried it in the comments).

`pfXML`/`dfXML` are defined in 'adodb.pas' and 'dbclient.pas' respectively.